# Error - Asynchronous adsense code in HTML

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, adsense

I'm a blogger and I monetize my blog with adsense. While coding or in fact adding asynchronous code inside `<head></head>`tag of my blog it appears that I have to add it like this:

```
 <script async="async" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

instead of like this:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

Otherwise it will show me an error. Can anyone explain why? Do you know if I'm allowed to add this (according to adsense)?

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Comment: Error parsing XML, line 1523, column 21: Attribute name "async" associated with an element type "script" must be followed by the ' = ' character

Comment: @SLaks __CAPS MAKE IT EVEN ANGREIR?!__ OP: you're getting the error becauuse the code it needs isn't ready yet and you're trying to use it.

Comment: @user3289647: No; that's not the error.

Comment: @user3289647 is your page of type XHTML perhaps and not HTML5 doctype?

Comment: Also yes - you are allowed to add it according to the TOS of adesese.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum it is a blogspot blog , and are you sure its allowed ? because im really paranoid about it

Comment: @user3289647 google will not sue you, you can count on that. However, I'm also not convinced this will work since `async` is not a valid attribute on a script tag in XHTML. I suggest you remove the async keyword altogether and place the script at the bottom of the body section.

Comment: and btw thanks all for the replies by the way i love this place i dont need to wait weeks until i get an answer everyone is helpful here :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum well they will not sue me but they can cancel my account since im not allowed to change their ad code but i hear that changing minor changes is however allowed

Answer (score 17):

Use this code instead on any of them... I'm currently using this...Try it

```js
<script async='async' src='http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You're writing an XHTML document (either because of the `Content-Type` or an XML declaration).

Therefore, the entire document must be valid XML.

Unlike regular HTML, all XML attributes must have values.

Comment: Does it have any implications on the google adsense TOS?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Google does not care whether your page is XHTML or tag soup

Comment: Is async a valid attribute on a script tag in xhtml? ref: http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-script-1.mod

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution for the same problem with Hubspot Tracking Code with Blogger.

When adding the following code to the theme HTML in Blogspot, I get an error.

> Error parsing XML, line 2490, column 62: Attribute name "async" associated with an element type "script" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

```
<!-- Start of HubSpot Embed Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" id="hs-script-loader" async defer src="//js.hs-scripts.com/xxxxxx.js"></script>
<!-- End of HubSpot Embed Code -->
```

I fixed it be using the above fix changing `async defer` to `async="async defer"`

```
<!-- Start of HubSpot Embed Code 17/03/2017-->
<script type="text/javascript" id="hs-script-loader" async="async defer" src="//js.hs-scripts.com/2336222.js"></script>
<!-- End of HubSpot Embed Code -->
```

Comment: Note that the async attribute and the defer attribute are separate attributes in HTML. You should change it to `async="async" defer="defer"`.